# preg_replace for finding a string and changing multiple different strings in it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

There are strings in a long text as:

```
<fn id="T1FN1"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fn id="T2FN1"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fn id="T2FN2"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fn id="F12FN5"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
```

etc...

I want to find 
    `<fn  </fn>` in a text and delete 
    `<p> and </p>`
just from these strings, the string between `<p> and </p>` would not be deleted. I try some preg_replace, but not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a nested regex:

```
$html = '<fn id="T1FN1"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
        <fn id="T2FN1"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
        <fn id="T2FN2"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
        <fn id="F12FN5"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>';

preg_replace_callback('/<fn[^>]*>.*?<p>.*?</p>.*?</fn>/', function($matches){
    return preg_replace('/<p>|</p>/', '', $matches[0]);
}, $html);
```

Note: [this syntax requires PHP 5.3+](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). If you're running an older version, let me know and I'll provide the syntax for that.

Comment: I made some changes and it works fine. thanks a lot.  $html= preg_replace_callback('#<fn[^>]*>.*?<p>.*?</p>.*?</fn>#s', create_function('$matches', 'return preg_replace("#<p>|</p>#s","", $matches[0]);' ), $html);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$s=<<<HDOC
<fn id="T1FN1"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fn id="T2FN1"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fn id="T2FN2"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fn id="F12FN5"> anytext <p> sometext </p> </fn>
<fnn id="F12FN5"> anytext <p> these tags stay </p> </fnn>
<p> some text that stays with tags </p>

HDOC;
$pattern = '/(<fn[^>]*>[^<]*)<p>([^<]*)<\/p>([^<]*<\/fn>)/';
$replace = '\1\2\3';
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $s));
```

caveat: will only find one pair of `<p></p>` and anaytext cannot have tags in it